# Changing push button border style

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a custom dialog with a method that changes the dialog default push button.

During `WM_INITDIALOG` following function is used to draw focus rectangle on default button (button chosen by system)

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
// ...

// ensure focus rectangle is properly drawn around control with focus
PostMessageW(mhWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);
return TRUE;
```

Dialog class has method `SetDefaultControl` which lets me specify different button to be default after the dialog has been created:

```
bool Dialog::SetDefaultControl(DWORD ctrlID) const noexcept
{
    BOOL result = TRUE;

    // Get current default button
    const LRESULT status = SendMessageW(mhWnd, DM_GETDEFID, 0, 0);

    if (HIWORD(status) == DC_HASDEFID)
    {
        // remove focus rectangle from default
        result = PostMessageW(GetDlgItem(mhWnd, LOWORD(status)), BM_SETSTYLE, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, TRUE);
    }

    // change default button to specified ctrlID
    result = result && PostMessageW(mhWnd, DM_SETDEFID, ctrlID, 0);

    return result != FALSE;
}
```

Default dialog has OK and CANCEL buttons, during `WM_INITDIALOG` the OK button is set as default, later I set it CANCEL to be default by using above function, and this is what turns out:

[image]

What happens is that CANCEL button is the new default, however focus rectangle was not removed from previous default button which was the OK button.

`SetDefaultControl` handles this case by sending `BM_SETSTYLE` message to OK button, however I don't know what style should I send to remove the focus border from OK button.

According to MSDN to change button style:

> Sending a DM_SETDEFID message to change the default button will not
> always remove the default state border from the first push button. In
> these cases, the application should send a BM_SETSTYLE message to
> change the first push button border style.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dm-getdefid

I'm not sure how to proceed, what style should I set on previous default button to remove focus border state.

Push buttons were created with `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON`

Comment: `DM_SETDEFID` tells the dialog which button to activate when the user hits Enter, but does not update any styles to reflect this in the UI. You can use `GetWindowLong(hwndButton, GWL_STYLE)` to get the current style, then change `BS_PUSHBUTTON` to `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` (to make it have the default look) or change it back (to make it look non-default). Also, posting fake keyboard messages is not the way to trigger focus rectangles. Use `WM_CHANGEUISTATE`.

Comment: `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` docs is unclear to me, if I want to move focus rectangle from one button to another this won't work: `SendMessageW(hDlg, WM_CHANGEUISTATE, MAKEWPARAM(UIS_SET, UISF_HIDEFOCUS), 0)` neither following works `MAKEWPARAM(UIS_CLEAR, UISF_HIDEFOCUS)`

Comment: `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` is not for moving focus. It is for forcing the focus rectangle to be visible (normally hidden until the first press of TAB. To move focus, use `WM_NEXTDLGCTL`.

Comment: Now I have all the information needed to solve this problem! + need to learn about UI states. as always Raymond, thank you for your useful responses!

Comment: `WM_NEXTDLGCTL` solved my problem without the need for anything else discussed, you may want to write an answer.

Comment: Go ahead and post your own answer that is written to your satisfaction, then accept it. (I don't need the points.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank to comments by Raymond I come out with solution like this:

```
bool Dialog::SetDefaultControl(DWORD ctrlID) const noexcept
{
    // MSDN: WM_NEXTDLGCTL updates the default pushbutton border, sets the default control identifier, and
    // automatically selects the text of an edit control (if the target window is an edit control)
    return PostMessageW(mhWnd, WM_NEXTDLGCTL, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(GetDlgItem(mhWnd, ctrlID)), MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0)) != FALSE;
}
```

This works such that when `TAB` key is first time clicked it will move from the control that has focus to the next control with `BS_TABSTOP` style.

However one small issue persists that is likely by API design, when the dialog first time shows up, a button with focus does not have focus rectangle drawn, pressing `TAB` is required for it to appear.

Here is a sample dialog that is first time shown (OK button has focus and is properly drawn but no focus rectangle is set):

If you know why and how to make focus rectangle appear when the dialog is shown let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The `WM_INITDIALOG` Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dlgbox-programming-considerations#the-wm_initdialog-message) can be used to set the default input focus.

> Before returning from the `WM_INITDIALOG` message, the procedure should
> determine whether it should set the input focus to a specified
> control. If the dialog box procedure returns `TRUE`, the system
> automatically sets the input focus to the control whose window handle
> is in the `wParam` parameter. If the control receiving the default focus
> is not appropriate, it can set the focus to the appropriate control by
> using the `SetFocus` function. If the procedure sets the input focus, it
> must return `FALSE` to prevent the system from setting the default
> focus. The control receiving the default input focus is always the
> first control specified in the template that is **visible**, **not disabled**,
> and has the `WS_TABSTOP` style. If no such control exists, the system
> sets the default input focus to the first control in the template.

Comment: System may set input focus during or after dialog creation, but it won't draw focus rectangle which is not the same thing as input focus. A control may be default and have focus but this is distinct from focus rectangle which I don't know how to set to default control.